# Untar with exclusions of existing folder and delete files on disk which are not present in disk

Tags: linux

Suppose I have three files on disk as `f1`,`f2`,`f3` and one folder `testfolder`. In my archive only `f4`,`f5` files are present.

After an untar operation I want `f1`,`f2`,`f3` files to be removed/deleted as they are not present in archive. At the same time some files/folders need to be excluded and only `f4`,`f5` files with test folder should be there on the disk.

Is that possible? How would I do it?

Comment: Hello Aditi. What have you tried?

Comment: Remove the original files before extracting the archive. When you extract, exclude the file you don't want to extract.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose "tarfile.tar" is your tar archive, and "originaldir" is the directory where testfolder, f1, f2, f3 currently exist

```
$ mkdir untardir
$ ls
originaldir tarfile.tar untardir

$ tar -C untardir -xvf tarfile.tar
$ rsync -av originaldir/testfolder/ untardir/testfolder/
$ rsync --delete -av untardir/ originaldir/
$ rm -rf untardir
```